# Autorefactor long python import list

Tags: python, refactoring

I have some code with long, specific imports I'd like to automatically inline and refactor.

For example,

```
from module.file import (
thisclass,
thatclass,
functionA, 
...
functionAA, 
functionAB,
...
)
```

would become `import module.file as module_file` and all the usages would change to `module_file.functionA`, etc.  I have looked into `isort`, `black`, pycharm, VSCode, and `rope` but don't see anything that does this.  Is there a package or tool that could do this drudge work for me?

Comment: Short of writing some `ast` code, and then using https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse to put it back into python, i haven't ran into anything that does this. I think you should hand roll it..

Comment: It looks like the best option might be libCST, FWIW.

Comment: YES! I heard about this a while back and forgot the name, and all I found was the astunparse -- yes libCST is definitely my first choice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [libCST](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why_libcst.html) is the best answer.